# When to choose webservices?

Tags: web-services, api, sockets, web-applications

I'd like to give external access to a web application. Several applications on many clients will use this service extensively (hopefully), which will always lead to [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) functions on a database.

Is a webservice always the first choice? Is there any rule of thumb when to choose webservices, sockets, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on who your clients are, what kind of performance are you looking at, how well your clients know the technologies.

Sockets etc might give you a good performance speed but development time might increase for both, you and your clients.
SOAP web services established a standard quite some time back but now people are using REST web services more because of its simplicity and less overhead.
I am heavily impressed by the RESTful webservices offered by [twilio](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/)

I am sure that Twilio is receiving hundreds of thousands of calls a day and they are performing just well.
Have a look at the following articles for more understanding about them
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/
http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/13.%20Web%20Services.html

Answer (score 1):

The big benefit of web services is the ease of use and the predefined interface, but they are "slower" compared to low level socket communication, because for example the XML Requests/Respnses of a SOAP-Service needs to be created/interpreded.

So I would say if you open the service to "outsider" use web services unless speed is really the biggest concern.

Also because web services are mostly accessable through port 80 you have much less problems with proxy/firewalls than with a socket on a random other port.

If you are having a high work load cahcing is also very important because it can speed up the system dramaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a web services (SOAP or REST) whenever I can. It's easier to scale a web service than a home brew socket implementation and it takes less time to build a webservice.

Sockets is usually the preferred choice if you need two-way communication (I know that WCF has callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Webservice makes it a generic way for different type of clients and applications to exchange data also it is dependent on your architecure and infrastructure.

Socket programming is bit complex and some time may create problem in data exchange. It entirely depends on your fuctionaly requirements and architecure which should you use.

if your clients will consume this data from browsers of application then webservice is better choice.